# Is every group the commutator subgroup of some other group?

Tags: group-theory

This is a result I haven't been able to find. An answer for finite groups or general groups would be great. A simple proof would be appreciated if possible.

Comment: I googled «is every group a commutator group» and the second result was [this page](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_subgroup) which claims that «a group whose first two abelianizations are cyclic, but whose second derived subgroup is not trivial, cannot arise as a derived subgroup».

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Is there a familiar example of such a group?

Comment: $S_3$ is an example. It cannot be the derived subgroup of a group.

Comment: @NickyHekster Why not? It doesn't fulfill, me thinks, the characterization Mariano mentions, as $\;S_3''=(S_3')'=(A_3)'=1\;$

Comment: If a group $D$ is the commutator subgroup of some group $G$, the natural homomorphism $G \rightarrow Aut(D)$ induced by conjugation, maps the commutator subgroup $D$ of $G$ to the commutator subgroup $Aut(D)'$ of $Aut(D)$. Therefore we have $Inn(D) \subseteq Aut(D)'$. This necessary condition on $D$ 
easily implies that for $n \gt 2$ the dihedral groups $D_n$ and the symmetric groups $S_n$ cannot be commutator subgroups of any group.

Comment: @manthanomen Yes, $S_4$.